# SQLite Date Adjustment Incorrect

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I am trying to convert my date (15768) to a normal format within SQLite Studio....

I have the following formula that works but it's giving me the incorrect end result (it puts it in 1967 rather than the mid-2010's)

```
DATETIME(ReportDate,'unixepoch','localtime') ReportDate
```

Is it also possible to convert this to just the date, not time?

Comment: `DATETIME('15768','unixepoch','localtime')` returns `1970-01-01 ...` and not 1967.

Comment: Yes, but this should not be correct based on what I know about the data. I know these dates are inbetween 2010-2020

Comment: @RCarmody: which date is `15768` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case that your 5 digit dates represent the number of days since `1970-01-01`.
So you can try:

```
SELECT DATE('1970-01-01', ReportDate || ' day') ReportDate
FROM tablename
```

Result:

```
ReportDate
----------
2013-03-04
```

Comment: THANK YOU! What's relevant about 1-1-1970?

Comment: It's a date commonly used as base for storing dates (not the only one as I've also seen 1899-12-30!!!). It is also mentioned here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html